# How to fix gap between svg elements

Tags: html, svg, browser

### The Problem

I noticed a strange gap between a rect and a path that, according to the coordinates, should look like this:

[image: *image*]

but instead looks like this:

[image: *image*]

It occurs in Firefox, Edge and IE, in Chrome only in certain zoom levels or when adding Stoke.

---

### I tried to:

- [remove all white spaces (looks like the very same problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034337/odd-spacing-between-svg-elements)
- [add attribute `shape-rendering="crispEdges"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314587/abutted-rect-elements-in-svg-leave-a-tiny-gap)
- [move the elements closer together so that they would overlap (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/eu0n5Leq/17/)

  Improved the problem, but didn't fix it and introduced new ones (like stroke not matching).

Result in Chrome(v64.0.3282.140):
[image: Chrome]

Result in Firefox(v58.0.1):
[image: Firefox]

## Thanks for your consideration

---

### Example

```html
<svg>
  <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,60,10)">
    <rect width="60" height="10" x="-30" y="0" rx="5" ry="5"></rect>
    <path d="M15,10 C0,10 15,25 0,25 C-15,25 0,10 -15,10" ></path>
  </g>
</svg>

<style>
  g{
    stroke: red;
    fill: black;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of when its "wrong"?

Comment: the way the path's d attribute is written is weird. This line d="M 15 10 C 0 10 15 25 0 25 C -15 25 0 10 -15 10" should be d="M15,10 C0,10 15,25 0,25 C-15,25 0,10 -15,10"

Comment: Thanks for your replies @SergeyRudenko, i already posted a screenshot in the description, here is the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA9wK.png). Sadly writing the path the way you suggested didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko: svg supportsspaces instead of commas in point specifications

Answer (score 0):

The `rect`s outline seems to be rendered in color different from black.

Couldn't reproduce the behaviour on Chrome 63 (63.0.3239.132) without the style element, not even scanning through the zoom levels.

However, one possible fix is to close the path with the `closepath` specifier ( `Z` or `z` in the path spec; see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataClosePathCommand) for the pertinent portion of the svg specs):

```
<path d="M15,10 C0,10 15,25 0,25 C-15,25 0,10 -15,10"></path>
```

In case this modification does not suffice, complement the path to paint over the rectangle's outline along the x interval covered by the path-defined shape:

```
<path d="M15,10 C0,10 15,25 0,25 C-15,25 0,10 -15,10 l0,-1 L15,9 Z"></path>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @collapsar, i think i didn't express it clear enough what i'm trying to achieve. I want to style both elements with a stroke, so they look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/xOh9Zyf.png). Thats why i didn't use the `closepath` specifier. I edited my question and tried to make it more clear.